# Hacer child theme en WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Estoy intentando crear un child theme en WordPress con el fin de trastear en localhost y hacer algunas pruebas para meter scripts y algunas modificaciones.

1. He creado una carpeta llamada oceanwp-child que está en htdocs/circulogastromico/wp-content/themes/

2.Dentro tengo un archivo style.css con lo que he visto que hay que poner:

```
 /*
 Theme Name: oceanwp-child
 Version: 4.0
 Description: Tema hijo de A theme
 Template: OceanWP
 */
```

3. He creado el archivo functions.php con lo que he visto que hay que añadir(inserto imagen porque el código no se me formatea correctamente):

   [image: functions.php]
4. Aparece en WordPress correctamente y lo activo pero no muestra el contenido que había con el tema padre ni estilo ni nada. Solamente se muestra en blanco. He intentado copiar tambien los documentos index.php, header.php, etc, del tema padre al tema hijo, pero tampoco funciona asi.

¿Hay alguna manera, sin plugins de ser posible, de hacer una copia del tema y poder trastear sin cargarme el tema padre?

Answer (score 1):

Debes añadir la ruta del `css` original en una nueva línea después del cierre `*/`:

`@import url("../OceanWP/style.css");`

Con esto es suficiente para activar tu `child`, no es necesario el archivo `functions` para ello...

Puedes revisar este artículo: [Cómo usar child themes en WordPress](https://lesidea.com/cajondesastre/2017/02/02/como-usar-child-themes-en-wordpress/), que edité en su día si te interesa...

Comment: funciona salvo el header, que no coge el estilo totalmente. Si que contiene el menú y funcionan los enlaces pero el tamaño, color de fondo etc no lo coge. El body si funciona bien.

Comment: Había leído que la buena práctica es coger el estilo desde el functions.php, pero no lo consigo

Comment: Lo he conseguido con el functions.php modificando la URI del tema padre que estaba mal. No obstante tampoco coge el estilo para el header. Aunque se lo puedo modificar en Wordpress seguro que algo tengo mal para que sea así